# Knockout js. Is there a way to databind a textbox to both an observable and computed?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Here's my jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/bigtek/3rW9S/17/

My question is this:
The "txtSum" textbox contains the sum of the two other textboxes.
However, a user can enter a different number in the txtSum box.
In this case, I want the "txtSum" box to be highlighted in red to tell the users that the numbers don't add up.

Also, the allocate button will compute the two textboxes with their respective allocatpct.
When this happens, I want to compute with whatever number is in the txtSum box, regardless of whether it is synched or not.

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value:Sum" id="txtSum" />
```

(Am I doing this correctly?)

Hope this makes sense..  thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can, and it is demonstrated in the documentation [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) under the heading **Example 1: Decomposing user input**.

```
function MyViewModel() {
    this.firstName = ko.observable('Planet');
    this.lastName = ko.observable('Earth');

    this.fullName = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
        },
        write: function (value) {
            var lastSpacePos = value.lastIndexOf(" ");
            if (lastSpacePos > 0) { // Ignore values with no space character
                this.firstName(value.substring(0, lastSpacePos)); // Update "firstName"
                this.lastName(value.substring(lastSpacePos + 1)); // Update "lastName"
            }
        },
        owner: this
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

> In this example, the write callback handles incoming values by splitting the incoming text into “firstName” and “lastName” components, and writing those values back to the underlying observables.

Html:

```
<p>First name: <span data-bind="text: firstName"></span></p>
<p>Last name: <span data-bind="text: lastName"></span></p>
<h2>Hello, <input data-bind="value: fullName"/>!</h2>
```

**Edit:**

quick break down

- read: code you implement to return what will be displayed in the computed observable
- write: what is written back to the underlying observables.